# Why does my TSQL SELECT command spit out random data?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, t-sql

I am trying to write a function for ASP.NET that checks the existing IDs in a Table and returns an unused one for an INSERT command I am using elsewhere. However, this function spits out a 61-member array of random numbers when I only have 3 members in the Table.

```
public int getId()
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            string sql = @"select Id from dbo.Tasks";
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connString("db1")))
            {
                foreach (int a in Convert.ToString(cnn.Query(sql)).ToList())
                {
                    list.Add(a);
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) if (!list.Contains(x)) return x;
            return 99;
        }
```

```
Count = 61
83
121
115
116
101
109

//etc.

{ToDo.Controllers.HomeController}
```

However, this List doesn't even contain the existing IDs in the table, which is causing duplicate primary errors when Creating new rows.

Comment: Why the Convert.ToString?

Comment: What's happened is you have tried to convert the query result to a string, but the result is an `IEnumerable`, this cannot be converted to a string. All you will get is a single string describing the object type. You have then called `ToList` on that, which has converted that into a string of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a very poor performant approach to ID selection. I would suggest using an [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) (if you're using MySQL) or [`IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) if you're using SQLServer. Since you've tagged your question with both, I don't know which one you are using.

Having said that, onto your question:

```
string sql = @"select Id from dbo.Tasks order by Id"; // make sure you
                                                      // order by something
                                                      // to prevent random
                                                      // results
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connString("db1")))
{
    list = cnn.Query<int>(sql).ToList();
}

return list.Any() ? list.Min() : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! I'm still new to SQL (I'm using MySQL) so I'm just trying to get the concepts down for now, not really worried about execution speed yet.

Comment: Glad it helped! Enjoy the learning process!

Comment: Forget the speed, If you're in it for the learning process, don't do this either